# Racket REPL and Submodules

Tags: emacs, racket

Is there an easy way for me to load a submodule in the current file in racket-mode in emacs?

For example if I have the following file

```
#lang racket

(define (foo x)
  x)

(module+ sub
  (define (bar x y)
    x))
```

and I hit f5 in racket-mode to start the repl then `foo` is available but `bar` is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine [`dynamic-enter!`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/interactive.html) and [`quote-module-path`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Source_Locations.html#%28form._%28%28lib._syntax%2Flocation..rkt%29._quote-module-path%29%29) to do this.

Given a repl interaction for the code above that you posted:

```
> (require racket/enter syntax/location)
> (dynamic-enter! (quote-module-path sub))
> bar
#<procedure:bar>
```

Alternatively, you could use [`dynamic-require/expose`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=dynamic-require%2Fexpose#%28def._%28%28lib._rackunit%2Fmain..rkt%29._dynamic-require%2Fexpose%29%29) (the expose part allows you require things that are not provided), as done [here](http://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2013-May/058029.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering this, Leif! I just now opened [issue 151](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/issues/151) for this.

Comment: I just merged a commit to master, should flow through to MELPA shortly. `racket-run` now runs the innermost submodule enclosing point.

Comment: I should mention that the module definitions will not be available if you are using (1) `module+`, (2) errortrace i.e. `racket-error-context` other than `'low` or `'medium`, _and_ (3) Racket 6.2.1 or older. However it works if any of those conditions are absent. TL;DR it always works on Racket HEAD.

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way in DrRacket. You have to `provide` bar from the submodule, and `require` the submodule  to use it. Try the following code:

```
#lang racket

(define (foo x)
  x)

(module+ sub
  (define (bar x y)
    x)
  (provide bar))

;; (bar 1 2) -- undefined

(require (submod "." sub))
(bar 1 2) ;; -- works here
```